# coded ui support on microsoft edge

Tags: c#, cross-browser, coded-ui-tests

I was doing Cross-Browser testing for my Coded UI Scripts, for Web Application on VSTS 2017 Enterprise edition.

They are running fine for Latest Chrome & Firefox browsers but not working on Microsoft Edge browser.

I've tried installing Microsoft WebDriver for the same & have put that at the below said location:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Driver".
Still got no success.

Below is the Stack Trace of the Error/Exception i am getting:

> Test_New.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowserProxy.ProxyEdgeDriver'
>   from assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowserProxy,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Please let me know your inputs on this, if somebody can provide any help in resolving this.

Thanks,
Hardik Tewari